# Macro inside latex cite command?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, citing

I have a list of bibtex keys defined as `pmid123`, `pmid456`, `pmid789`, etc.

I want to be able to cite by doing the following: `\pmid{[123,456,789]}` so using xstring, I defined the following macro to clean up the keys:

```
\newcommand{\pmidhelper}[1]{
    \noexpandarg % suppress expansions made by xstring
    \StrSubstitute{#1}{,}{,pmid}[\x]
    \expandafter\StrSubstitute\expandafter{\x}{[}{pmid}[\x]%
    \expandafter\StrSubstitute\expandafter{\x}{]}{}[\x]%
    \x
}

\newcommand{\pmid}[1]{ \cite{\pmidhelper{#1}} }
```

But trying `\pmid{[123,456,789]}` gives me the error:

```
Illegal parameter number in definition of \@citeb. \pmid{[123,456,789]}
```

Any idea how I could go about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

It's the very common problem that `\StrSubstitute` is not “expandable”; you have to prepare the token list before passing it to `\cite`.

So it should be something like

```
\newcommand{\pmidhelper}[1]{% <--- don't forget
    \noexpandarg % suppress expansions made by xstring
    \StrSubstitute{#1}{,}{,pmid}[\x]%
    \expandafter\StrSubstitute\expandafter{\x}{[}{pmid}[\x]%
    \expandafter\StrSubstitute\expandafter{\x}{]}{}[\x]%
}

\newcommand{\pmid}[1]{{\pmidhelper{#1}\expandafter\cite\expandafter{\x}}}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\pmidhelper}[1]{% <--- don't forget
  \noexpandarg % suppress expansions made by xstring
  \StrSubstitute{#1}{,}{,pmid}[\x]%
  \expandafter\StrSubstitute\expandafter{\x}{[}{pmid}[\x]%
  \expandafter\StrSubstitute\expandafter{\x}{]}{}[\x]%
}

\newcommand{\pmid}[1]{%
  {\pmidhelper{#1}\expandafter\cite\expandafter{\x}}% 
}

\begin{document}

\pmid{[123,456,789]}

\end{document}
```

The console will show

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation `pmid123' on page 1 undefined on input line 15.

LaTeX Warning: Citation `pmid456' on page 1 undefined on input line 15.

LaTeX Warning: Citation `pmid789' on page 1 undefined on input line 15.
```

which means the correct keys have been picked up.

An alternative with `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\pmid}{m}
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l_tmpa_seq
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { pmid##1 }
   }
  \exp_args:Nx \cite { \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { , } }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\pmid{123,456,789}

\end{document}
```

The brackets `[` and `]` don't really play a role, so I removed them in this version.

If you need them in place, they can be removed by preprocessing the argument:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\pmid}{m}
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l_tmpa_seq
  \byo_process_pmid:n { #1 }
 }
\cs_new:Nn \byo_process_pmid:n
 {
  \__byo_process_pmid:w #1
 }
\cs_new:Npn \__byo_process_pmid:w [#1]
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { pmid##1 }
   }
  \exp_args:Nx \cite { \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { , } }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\pmid{[123,456,789]}

\end{document}
```

A more complex version that accepts both inputs, with or without brackets.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\pmid}{m}
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l_tmpa_seq
  \byo_process_pmid:n { #1 }
 }
\tl_new:N \l__byo_input_tl
\cs_new:Nn \byo_process_pmid:n
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__byo_input_tl { #1 }
  \regex_replace_once:nnN { \A \[+ (.*) \]+ \Z } { \1 } \l__byo_input_tl
  \clist_map_inline:Vn \l__byo_input_tl
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { pmid##1 }
   }
  \exp_args:Nx \cite { \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { , } }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \clist_map_inline:nn { V }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\pmid{[123,456,789]}

\pmid{aaa,bbb,ccc}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The second approach looks much more elegant. The first one messes up in my larger document. How can I modify the expl3 version to use the brackets?

Comment: @by0 What’s the purpose of the brackets?

Comment: They're used by pubtex.herokuapp.com to fetch the bibtex entries. It's much more work for me to change the parser than it would be to change the macro. Would it be possible?

Comment: @by0 I added the version with the brackets. It could also be possible to have both, if needed.